# JAVA JsonPath get selected paths using regex

Tags: java, json, jsonpath, json-path-expression

Given the following Json

```
{
   "id":"MENU_FULL_V2",
   "version":"MENU_FULL_V2",
   "type":"MAIN",
   "icon":"shopping-bag-r",
   "description":"This is the description {$.description}",
   "order":15000,
   "code":"code",
   "filter":"{$.contractedServices[*].contractId}",
   "status":"ENABLED",
   "contextData":{
      "docType":"{$.documentType}",
      "docNumber":"{$.documentNumber}",
      "organizationName":"{$.name}",
      "contractedServices":"{$.contractedServices[*]}"
   },
   "children":[
      {
         "id":"MENU_CHILD_1",
         "version":"MENU_FULL_V2",
         "type":"CHILD",
         "description":"This is the description {$.description}"
      },
      {
         "id":"MENU_CHILD_2",
         "version":"MENU_FULL_V2",
         "type":"CHILD",
         "description":"This is the description {$.description}"
      }
   ]
}
```

How can I return a List of string which contains all the paths to the values that has `{ }` in their value.

Is there a way to get all the values that match this regular expresion [see](https://regex101.com/r/2GhsKu/1)

So far I have this.

```
Configuration conf = Configuration.builder()
   .options(Option.AS_PATH_LIST).build();

List<String> pathList = JsonPath.using(conf).parse(json).read("//GET ALL PATHS THAT MATCH REGEX");
```

The expected output for `pathList` should contain all paths that have values that have `{ }`

ie:

```
"$['description']",
"$['filter']",
"$['contextData']['docType']",
"$['contextData']['docNumber']"
```

Note that the list is not complete, but it should contain all the paths that have values with `{ }`

Answer (score 0):

You may consider another library *Josson* to do the transformation.

https://github.com/octomix/josson

```
Josson josson = Josson.fromJsonString(yourJsonString);

JsonNode node = josson.getNode(
    "flatten('.','[%d]')" +
    ".entries()" +
    ".[value=~'.*\\{.*}.*']*" +
    ".concat('$.',key)");
node.forEach(elem -> System.out.println(elem.asText()));
```

**Output**

```
$.description
$.filter
$.contextData.docType
$.contextData.docNumber
$.contextData.organizationName
$.contextData.contractedServices
$.children[0].description
$.children[1].description
```